# l_2 norm matrix eigenvalue equality

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Hello how to show the following:

$||A||_2$ = $\sqrt{ \text{largest eigenvalue of }  A^{T}A}$

for any $m\times n$ matrix $A$.

Thank you

Comment: Hello, [how to ask questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A^TA = U\Lambda U^T$ where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $A^TA$. Then
\begin{align*}
\|A\|_2^2 & = \sup_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_2^2}{\|x\|_2^2}
= \sup_{x \ne 0} \frac{x^TA^TAx}{x^Tx}
= \sup_{x \ne 0} \frac{x^TU\Lambda U^Tx}{x^TUU^Tx}
= \sup_{y \ne 0} \frac{y^T\Lambda y}{y^Ty} = \text{largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for the answer why is the last equality true?

Comment: By the change of variable $y = U^Tx \Leftrightarrow x = Uy$.

Comment: I mean why is it equal to the largest eigenvalue of A^tA?? Thanks..

Comment: Because $\Lambda$ is diagonal. The optimal choice is to pick $y = e_i$, the $i$-th basis vector, when the $i$-th element of $\Lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

We can easily generalize Tunococ's proof considering $A\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ and $P\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ unitary matrix such that $P^hA^hAP=\mbox{diag }(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ where $\lambda_i\geq 0$ are the eigenvalues of $A^hA$.